# How can importing from folder without specifying file work?

Tags: javascript, import

I'm using a downloaded template. There I can see the following:

in App.js it imports: `import theme from 'src/theme';`

in theme there are three files:

1. src/theme/index.js
2. src/theme/shadows.js
3. src/theme/typography.js

in src/theme/index.js it exports:
`export default theme;`

Nothing is exported in shadows and typography.

Question: How does JS know that "theme" is in src/theme/index.js?
I would have expected the import statement to be: `import theme from 'src/theme/index';`

Comment: Path resolution to actual modules is part of module bundlers implementation. Node does it along with bundlers like webpack. You can configure it to some different file

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not working in node, I'm working in React...